# Linked object's constructor property not overriden on re-assigning prototype

Tags: javascript

Let' say I have this code.

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo; // true
var a = new Foo();
a.constructor === Foo; // true
```

So basically here `a.contructor` returns Foo by the process of delegation and gets that value from `Foo.prototype.constructor`.

Ok. Now if I over write Foo.prototype as

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo; // true
var a = new Foo();
Foo.prototype = {};
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo; // false
a.constructor === Foo; // true;
```

The last two lines are just not consumable. Shouldn't `a.constructor` also gets modified and return the value same as `Foo.prototype.constructor` since the a is linked to Foo.prototype after all and Javascript doesn't creates copies but linkages between objects ( delegation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Javascript doesn't creates copies but linkages between objects ( delegation )

Not really, it stores references to the objects. Now in your case `Foo.prototype` and `a[[prototype]]` are referencing the same object, then you change `Foo.prototype` but the reference of `a[[prototype]]` still points to the old one. If you however do:

```
 Foo.prototype.constructor = null;
```

Then both comparisons will be false.Or you rewrite both references:

```
 Foo.prototype = {};
 Object.setPrototypeOf(a, Foo.prototype); // thats like a[[prototype]] = Foo.prototype
```

Comment: Ok. I understood this now. This statement `Javascript doesn't creates copies but linkages between objects ( delegation )` holds. Just that we are doing the reassignment and then in this case new object is supposed to get a new memory location.